# Find the rightmost occurrence using strstr() in C

Tags: c

I want to find the rightmost occurrence of a string inside another string and return it's position. I saw three posts like that [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591671/find-the-rightmost-occurence-of-a-character-in-c) uses tables only, but I want to use `strstr()`. The problem with `strstr()` is that finds the leftmost occurrence of the string, but I want the rightmost, so what I've tried to do is reverse the `strstr()` and make it work from right to left with this piece of code.

```
int StrInd(char *MainStr, char *SecondStr){
 int i;
 i = strlen(MainStr);
 while (i >= 0) {
     if ( strstr( (MainStr + i)-1, SecondStr ) != NULL ) {  // found it
        return i;
     }
     i--;
 }
}
```

The problem with this code is that it doesn't appear the strings if they exist only one time. So for example when you give the string "halolololele", and you search the string "le", it will return 11, but if you search the string "ha" it will return 0.

Where is the flaw in the code, and why it gives different values?

Here is the full code too.

```
int str_index(char *MainStr, char *SecondStr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int Ans, Seclen = 256,Mainlen = 256;
    char *SecondStr = malloc(Seclen);
    char *MainStr = malloc(Mainlen);

    printf("Give the first string: ");
    fgets(MainStr,Mainlen,stdin);
    printf("Give the second string: ");
    fgets(SecondStr,Seclen,stdin);

    Ans = StrInd(MainStr,SecondStr);
    printf("The position of the string is in: %d", Ans);

    free(MainStr);
    free(SecondStr);
    return 0;
}

int StrInd(char *MainStr, char *SecondStr){
    int i;
    i = strlen(MainStr);
    while (i >= 0) {
        if ( strstr( (MainStr + i)-1, SecondStr ) != NULL ) {  // found it
            return i;
        }
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: The leftmost occurrence of `ha` in `halolololele` is indeed at index 0.

Comment: 1. You don't need `strstr`, a `strncmp` would do. 2. Start at `end - srch_len` where `srch_len` is the length of your search term. 3. Do you want `found_pos + srch_len - 1` here?

Comment: Oh, so i got it it starts from 0, then why when i search "le" doesn't return 10?

Comment: `StrInd("halolololele", "ha")` returns 1. Please check the details before publishing a question here!

Comment: You think i didn't run the code? I am trying to debug it 3+ hours now, and every time i do this it gives me 0.

Comment: It nevertheless returns 1, not 0! Your question details are wrong, but your function is mostly fine. Just return `i-1` instead of `i`, and `-1` (or some other value indicating that no sub-string was found) at the end of the function.

Comment: If you an OP are getting different values, then maybe UB?  We have no idea what the OP is calling this function with - maybe the parameters are invalid.

Comment: That's why i have included the full code above, check it out please! :) And Tell me if you can see any flaws!

Comment: 'le\n' will be found at the end of the buffer.  'ha\n' will not be found at the start.

Comment: 'halolololele\n\0' ihas a strlen() of 13.

Comment: So i should reduce my strlen(MainStr) by 2?

Comment: Not really.  You should understand that the strings you passed have newline chars at the end, and handle that as you so desire/design.  You could strip off the '\n' before calling your function, eg. by blasting it with a '\0', then see what you get.  If it's not what you want, change it.  If it still misbehaves, run it under your debugger.

Comment: And how do i blast it with a '\0' and by even blasting it, i will still have the '\0' character in my string, so it will be the normal characters that the user gave me with '\n' and '\0', right?

Comment: You have to have the null terminator.  C char arrays that represent text MUST have a null at the end - it's the only way to detect their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question says that the examples return positions 11 and 0, but to be consistent, either the first example should be *index* 10, or the second example should be *position* 1.

This shows one way to find the rightmost occurrence of a substring in a string (from the left). Just feed the pointer to each occurrence (+1) back into `strstr` like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *ptr = argv[1];
    char *found = NULL;
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Syntax: test <string> <substring>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while ((ptr = strstr(ptr, argv[2])) != NULL) {
        found = ptr++;
    }
    if (found) {
        printf("Found '%s' in '%s' at position %u\n", argv[2], argv[1], (unsigned)(found - argv[1] + 1));
    } else {
        printf("Did not find '%s' in '%s'\n", argv[2], argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
>test halolololele le
Found 'le' in 'halolololele' at position 11

>test halolololele ha
Found 'ha' in 'halolololele' at position 1
```